# Trap keypress using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-shortcuts

I have written a code block to trap key press on `Ctrl + s`it works and an alert has been placed when the event has ran to show me that the code block has successfully ran. later this code block will be replaced by a save command.

However I am having some trouble as the first time `Ctrl + s` is pressed it works however every time afterwards the `s` button alone triggers the event

here is the code block:

```
var isCtrl = false;
ck.on('contentDom', function (evt) {
    ck.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
        if (event.data.$.keyCode === 17) isCtrl = false;
    });

    ck.document.on('keydown', function (event) {

        if (event.data.$.keyCode === 17) isCtrl = true;
        if (event.data.$.keyCode === 83 && isCtrl === true) {
    //The preventDefault() call prevents the browser's save popup to appear.
   //The try statement fixes a weird IE error.
            try {
                event.data.$.preventDefault();
            } catch (err) { }

            alert('ctrl-s');

            return false;
        }
    });

}, ck.element.$);
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post is for anyone who has also had trouble with this problem, I have now solved it. The problem with my original code block is that once `isCtrl` was set as true it remained true. which meant that when time came again to check if it was pressed it didn't matter whether it was pressed again as it was already set to true. there for I have added a line to change it back to false when the conditional statements have ran.

Here is the new code block:

```
    var isCtrl = false;
    ck.on('contentDom', function (evt) {
        ck.document.on('keyup', function (event) {
            if (event.data.$.keyCode === 17) isCtrl = false;
        });
        ck.document.on('keydown', function (event) {
            if (event.data.$.keyCode == 17) isCtrl = true;
            if (event.data.$.keyCode == 83 && isCtrl === true) {
                //The preventDefault() call prevents the browser's save popup to appear.
                //The try statement fixes a weird IE error.
                try {
                    event.data.$.preventDefault();
                } catch (err) { }
                alert('ctrl-s');
                isCtrl = false;
                return false;
            }

        });

    }, ck.element.$);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to perform ctrl+s command in jquery that works every time:

```
$(window).keypress(function(event) {
    if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;
    alert("Ctrl-S pressed");
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way you could look at the original code and help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to make a JSFiddle for your code @NafisRahman?

Comment: no sorry, its on a CMS platform developed by my company it uses ckeditor as a text editor and that is the code ive been messing around with to get the short cut working

Comment: i added the code in my question straight after ckeditor is initialised and im aware that ckeditor has its own hotkey functionality but my boss wanted me to add the functionality this way rather than the ckeditors way